# Negative elevation angle

Tags: orbital-mechanics, low-earth-orbit, satellite-constellation, gps-radio-occultation

What does it mean to have negative values of elevation angle from the low-Earth orbiting (LEO) satellite? Can the negative values of elevation angle be useful?

Comment: So negative elevation simply refers to anything below the plane of the object. So to be clear, are you referring to an observer on the LEO satellite looking below the plane of the satellite? Or are you referring to an observer on the ground referring to an LEO satellite that is below the horizon? Both situations are “useful”, the former is used in satellite-to-ground communications and observation and the later is used to predict when the satellite will come over the horizon.

Comment: @AnthonyStevens, thank you for your insight.